# python class [] function

Tags: python

I recently moved from ruby to python and in ruby you could create self[nth] methods how would i do this in python?

in other words you could do this

```
a = myclass.new
n = 0
a[n] = 'foo'
p a[n]  >> 'foo'
```

Comment: Can you describe what `self[nth]` meant in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the light side ;-)

It looks like you mean [`__getitem__(self, key)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__). and [`__setitem__(self, key, value)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__).

Try:

```
class my_class(object):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return some_value_based_upon(key) #You decide the implementation here!

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return store_based_upon(key, value) #You decide the implementation here!


i = my_class()
i[69] = 'foo'
print i[69]
```

**Update (following comments):**

If you wish to use tuples as your key, you may consider using a `dict`, which has all this functionality inbuilt, *viz:*

```
>>> a = {}
>>> n = 0, 1, 2
>>> a[n] = 'foo'
>>> print a[n]
foo
```

Comment: could this method allow for multiple dimensions? ie. i[0][3][2]

Comment: Provided that the objects returned by `i[0]` and `i[0][3]` implement `__getitem__()` [for getting] and `__setitem__()` [for setting], yes.

Comment: if i[0, 1, 2] was called would key be a tube?

Comment: In this case, (0, 1, 2) as a tuple would be the key, yes. You may also consider using a `dict` at this point: a = {}; a[n] = 'foo'; print a[n];

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you can pass slices to `__getitem__`, so `i[1:3:5]` would pass `slice(1, 3, 5)` in as the key.

Answer (score 2):

You use [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).